# Popup for Google OAuth not working with AWS Amplify/Cognito in Angular?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to set up sign in via Google OAuth for my AWS Amplify project.

**The expected behavior:** It should open up a pop-up like in a Firebase project.

**What's happening now:** We are using Cognito and it basically opens up another web page within the app to log in via Google into the Cognito User Pool instead of the popup like what you see in a Firebase project.

Any help here would be super helpful!!

Comment: I think you should specify OAuth provider, `Auth.federatedSignIn(provider: "Google")`

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? trying to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

By checking the code on aws-amplify I've seen they have a default `urlOpener` that looks like this:

```js
const SELF = '_self';

export const launchUri = (url: string) => {
    const windowProxy = window.open(url, SELF);
    if (windowProxy) {
        return Promise.resolve(windowProxy);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject();
    }
};
```

The good thing is that you can override that in your amplify `configure` call, like this:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  ...yourConfig,
  oauth: {
  urlOpener: (url) => {
      const left = (window.screen.width - 600 ) / 2;
      const top = (window.screen.height - 549 ) / 2;
      const windowProxy = window.open( url, "center window",
        `resizable = yes, width=600,height=549,top=${top},left=${left}`);
      return Promise.resolve(windowProxy)
    }
```

and do whatever you want to display the oauth URL. I don't think they have implemented an straight-forward 'popup' option yet afaik. Hope it helps

Comment: but after login, it doesn't close the popup.