# Google Login with cognito in a new popup window

Tags: amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

I have Cognito for user management and I have integrated the Google login with that and in my React app I have

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: "google"})
```

and it takes the user to the Gmail account selection page in the same tab. I am looking around if it can just open a new window popup instead of opening in the same tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349893/popup-for-google-oauth-not-working-with-aws-amplify-cognito-in-angular This link helped

Comment: but after login, it doesn't close the popup. any solution for that?

Comment: @ChandlerBing

```
Hub.listen('auth', (data: any) => {
  if (get(data, 'payload.event') === 'signIn') {
    if (window.opener) {
      window.close();
      window.opener.postMessage('social-login');
    }
  }
});
```
I am doing this to close the event

Comment: thanks, it does close the popup but the state of aws-amplify doesnt update, meaning it does not realize that user has singed in so it keeps it loading state.